# Sitecore Webform for Marketers response on success page

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Using **Sitecore** and **Web Forms for Marketers**, how would one go about outputting the result from a webservice on the "success" page or similar.

- We are using a custom Save-action, that is calling a WebService and providing the form field values.
- The WebService are doing some security checks.
- The WebService are querying an external MSSQL DB, and returning this result.

How could we output this response from the WebService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If you have a generic success message per form, you can set the success page url to a page and load appropriate sublayout to pull from your service.

If the success message varies based on the information the user entered, you could create a custom submit action and take care of routing to the right success url with url params to support the logic.

Comment: Yep, that was also the solution I came around to. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways to do this, but playing within the framework of Web Forms for Marketers is going require more work, such as overriding the normal behavior of the success message to introduce some special formatting and logic (but just in certain cases).

I think you'll have an easier time just having your form **redirect on success to a fresh separate page** that you build. You can have it carry along a query string parameter or session variable to match it with the form that was just submitted or to pass along an important id used in the results. On the new page (now not tied into the Web Forms for Marketers framework), you can have all your logic that makes the database calls and returns the proper results.